# Emacs report a process which does not exist

Tags: process, ubuntu

When start Emacs from the terminal as

```
 me@mbp: ~$ emacs --deamon
```

It prompts that

[image]

However, there does not exist  such a pocesses

```
me@mbp~$ ps 8559
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
me@mbp:~$ ps -el |grep 8559
```

Why could pop such a prompt

There is a file

```
 -rw-r--r--   1 me me     4 Jan 16 14:44  .emacs.desktop.lock
```

should I delete it ?

Comment: This is probably irrelevant, but did you *actually* run `emacs --deamon` ?  That's not spelled correctly.

Comment: It could be the case that the process Emacs is complaining dies right after the message. I don't know how desktop files are handled exactly, but there could be lock files, and whatever process that Emacs is mentioning just failed to clean up the lock.

Comment: thank you, there is a lock file, should I remove it? @DoMiNeLa10

Comment: @Alice it's probably the culprit, so you should try removing it.

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report about this: Emacs should detect when such a lock is stale.